# C++ string and char comparaison

Tags: c++, string, char

i have a string `"8120, 8120NGE, 8120NG, 8130, 8130NG, 8130NGE"`.

And i have a `char*` `(0x0012d094 "8130")`

I want to see if the "8130" is in. That exact word.

So i am using

```
  istringstream iss(boards);
  string token;
  AVBOOL foundBool=FALSE;
  while(std::getline(iss, token, ','))
  {
    const char * compareToken = token.c_str();  
    token.compare(board);     // with that : it doesn't work cause "8130" is not    equal   0x0012d094 "8130"
    if(strcmp(compareToken,board)==0) //with that it doesnt work cause 0x0012cef0 " 8130" is not equal 0x0012d094 "8130"
      {
        foundBool=TRUE;
      }
  }
```

So the question is how do i compare a string with a char * .

Do I need to convert the char into a string and then use string.compare
OR 
Do i need to convert the string into a char and use strcmp?
OR
Do i need to do something else?

I am kind of lost here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both.

I prefer use .c_str() method with strcmp() C function because it doesn't create an string object.

Comment: AFAIK, `std::string` provides overloads `bool operator==(const string&,const char*)` and `bool operator==(const char*,const string&)` and `token` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

how about `boards.find( token )`

if you need it to not have alphanumeric characters after, just check if there is such

and if so search again from that position

cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Armen: he he, I edited answer so as to make your comment seem meaningless :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would using a `std::set` suit your needs ?

```
std::set<std::string> boards;
while (std::getline(iss, token, ',')) {
    boards.insert(token);
}
if (boards.find(board) != boards.end()) {
    // we found it
}
```

Note that this does not take into account whitespace that might be in the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you're confused about comparison - you can compare a `string` and a `const char*` just fine! Both `string::compare(const char*)` and `strcmp` will return `0` when the contained characters are equal:

```
string one = "pl";
string two = "ex";
const char* too = "plex";

int main()
{
        string three = one + two;
        cout << three.compare(too) << endl;
        cout << strcmp(three.c_str(), too) << endl;
}
```

will print

```
0
0
```

Your actual application problem is that you probably want to split a string by `", "`, which you can't do with standard library tools. If you can't generally get rid of the spaces as mentioned in Mazurov's answer you will need a tokenizer that accepts string separators.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-write your code so that it strips whitespace before reading tokens.  You can adjust your loop as such:

```
istringstream iss(boards);
string token;
bool found = false;
while((iss >> std::ws) && std::getline(iss,token,','))
{
    found |= (token == board);
}
```

The loop can also be optimized to stop when the token is found:

```
while(!found && (iss >> std::ws) && std::getline(iss,token,','))
{
    found = (token == board);
}
```